# How do I make useEffect run every time a variable stored with useRef is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-ref

I am trying to have useEffect run every time it changes a variable, but changes to the variable are lost on every re-render.

If I try to store the variable between renders using useRef, useEffect doesn't run because it cannot detect changes to a ref. I found [an article](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780) that shows how to effectively pass a ref to useEffect but I am not sure how to use this in the context of my problem.

here is my code where a ref is passed to useEffect:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const divOffset = useRef(0);
  let scrollPosition = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    divOffset.current = linearInterpolation(
      divOffset.current,
      scrollPosition,
      0.07
    );
    divOffset.current = Math.floor(divOffset.current * 100) / 100;
    document.querySelector(
      "#main"
    ).style.transform = `translateX(-${divOffset.current}px);`;
  }, [scrollPosition]);

  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  };

  function linearInterpolation(x1, x2, easingValue) {
    return (1 - easingValue) * x1 + easingValue * x2;
  }

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <div className="layer1" />
      <div className="layer2" />
      <div className="layer3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` can detect changes to ref values, but only when a render happens. To make react re-render your component, you'd need to use a state for the `scrollPosition`.

Comment: But it looks like you don't actually want a state and re-renders here. Just install the scroll handler only once, and directly change the `main.style.transform` from it. No extra refs, no extra mutable variables. (You may want to use a ref to the DOM element though instead of calling `document.querySelector` every time)

Comment: @Bergi I may have explained this poorly, but I need the divOffset variable to be updated multiple times, and each time divOffset is updated it will cause a re-render, resetting the variable. The problem is that divOffset needs the previous value of divOffset to update itself.

Comment: Then use a state, not a ref. But why do you think you need a re-render?

Comment: @Bergi i assumed i did because the i wanted to update the position of the main div incrementally using css transform, is there a better way of doing this? For context the code is to give an inertia based scrolling effect to the div

Comment: No, to update the position of the div you can just directly modify the DOM, like you did. You don't need react to re-render the component. That would only be necessary if you wanted to show/hide different components/elements depending on the position.

Answer (score -2):

In React, `useEffect` runs when the dependencies specified in its dependency array change. However, as you've noticed, changes to variables stored with `useRef` are not considered dependencies by default, so `useEffect` won't run when they change. To make `useEffect` run every time a variable stored with `useRef` changes, you can use a combination of `useEffect` and `useRef` to capture the previous value and compare it to the current value. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```js
import { useRef, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const divOffset = useRef(0);
  const scrollPositionRef = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    divOffset.current = linearInterpolation(
      divOffset.current,
      scrollPositionRef.current,
      0.07
    );
    divOffset.current = Math.floor(divOffset.current * 100) / 100;
    document.querySelector(
      "#main"
    ).style.transform = `translateX(-${divOffset.current}px);`;
  }, [divOffset]);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    scrollPositionRef.current = window.scrollY;
  };

  function linearInterpolation(x1, x2, easingValue) {
    return (1 - easingValue) * x1 + easingValue * x2;
  }

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <div className="layer1" />
      <div className="layer2" />
      <div className="layer3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this modified code:

1. Add a `scrollPositionRef` using `useRef` to store the `scrollPosition`. This allows us to track changes to `scrollPosition` across re-renders.
2. In the `useLayoutEffect`, change the dependency array to `[divOffset]`. This means that the effect will run whenever `divOffset` changes. Since we're updating `divOffset.current` within the effect based on `scrollPositionRef.current`, it will run whenever `scrollPositionRef.current` changes.
3. In the `handleScroll` function, update `scrollPositionRef.current` with the new scroll position.

This way, the `useLayoutEffect` will run every time `scrollPositionRef.current` changes, effectively achieving your goal of running the effect whenever the `scrollPosition` changes.

Comment: "*The effect will run whenever `divOffset` changes. […] it will run whenever `scrollPositionRef.current` changes.*" - which one is it now? This answer does not make sense.

Comment: @Bergi LLM/AI Hallucinations?

Comment: @AdrianMole Most probably. But I try to point out only objective weaknesses in comments (so that other readers get suspicious as well) and keep stating my suspicions to mod flags :-)